# NFS Stale File Handle on New Mounts

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I'm having troubles adding NFS mount points on CentOS 6 servers (server and clients).

I have an NFS server with multiple mount points that have existed for years. I've added a couple new mount points and neither are working. I've restarted the NFS server multiple times and tried mounting the share on multiple clients but both shares fail with the same error, i.e.:

```
# mount -t nfs my-server:/test2 /test
# ls -atlr /test
ls: cannot open directory /test: Stale file handle
```

All of my exports have the same settings (except the mount point). Here's the new one:

```
/test    10.0.0.0/8(rw,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

From the NFS server the new mounts are all there:

```
ls -altr /test2
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6 Feb 23 10:39 test.txt
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 63 Feb 23 10:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 10 Feb 23 10:55 test
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 44 Feb 23 10:55 .

showmount -e localhost

Export list for localhost:
/test2                  10.0.0.0/8
/test                        10.0.0.0/8
/logs            10.0.0.0/8
/backup1           10.0.0.0/8
/logs2                  10.0.0.0/8
/users                  10.0.0.0/8
/repo       10.8.0.0/8
/backups3 10.8.0.0/8
/backup4             10.8.0.0/8
```

The mounts do successfully mount on the client but any attempt to access the mounts fails. Permissions don't seem to be an issue. **What am I missing here? How can I debug this issue?**